# Cropping tool using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a cropping tool using javascript. The tool should support elliptical, circular and rectangular cropping.

Which javascript library can i use to achieve this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.hotscripts.com/blog/javascript-image-cropping-scripts/) site may help you get what you want. some of them are free but others are not.